# File Change Not Being Shown in Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm working with an angular app. We use docker images for deployments.

In the angular app, there are some private NPM package being used. I need to display the version of these packages. I pull the version of the package from the package-lock file (`packageLockJson.dependencies["@myPrivateNPMPkg"].version`).

In our docker container, we have commands to always get the latest major 1 version of the private packages (`RUN npm install @myPrivateNPMPkg@1`). However, I recently noticed that the package version wasn't being displayed correctly in the application.

After some testing, I validated that the latest major 1 version of the package is being installed and used in the app, but it seems that the package-lock.json file isn't being updated in the docker container, so it shows an old version of the package that's being used.

How can I get the changes to take affect in package-lock.json in the docker image?

Here's my full dockerfile (I replaced some things with dummy values):

```
FROM artifactory-aws.my-domain.com/base-containers/node:16-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app/pattern-library
COPY package.json ./
COPY .npmrc .

RUN npm install
RUN npm install @myPrivateNPMPkg@1
COPY . /app/pattern-library

RUN npm run build:pl

# production
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN apk del freetype nginx-module-image-filter
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=builder /app/pattern-library/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Make sure you `COPY package-lock.json` into the image.  The third line in the Dockerfile copies the `package.json` but doesn't include the lock file.